# Subspace of strictly positive entries

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Can someone show me how to solve this question.

> Is the set of all vectors in $R^3$ with strictly positive entry a subspace?

Thanks

Comment: Hi @patricia-jade, welcome to Maths SE or sort of ... Can you show us your steps towards the resolution of this problem...?

Comment: This will help you http://math.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Which definition of subspace do you know? What have you tried to solve the problem?

Comment: let E = {(x,y,z)|x>0, y>0,z>0}. let u <a,b,c> and v<d,e,f>. let's check whether u + v belong to E. u+v = <(a+d), (b+e), (c+f)>. so (a+d) >0, (b+e)>0 and (c+f) > 0. u+v belong to E. let check whether (lambda) x  belong to E. (lambda) u = (lambda) <a,b,c> which is greater than 0 . is that correct

Comment: @patriciajade please put your answer in your comment in the question. It will help anyone who have the knowledge to be able to help you where your issue lies

Answer (score 1):

To determine whether something is a linear a subspace you have to verify that it is itself a vector space.

There are usually about two things that go wrong: Either $0$ is not in the space or $x,y$ are in the space but $x+y$ is not.

This later "flaw" is generally referred to as "not being closed" which is short for "not closed with respect to vector addition".

These are the two things that go wrong most often but sometimes it also happens that there are no inverses. After, first and foremost, a vector space is a group and if it does not satisfy the group axioms it cannot be a group.

In your example, two of the three things I mention go wrong. Do you see which?

Answer (score -1):

> Is the set of all vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with strictly positive entry a subspace?

Let
$$
\mathbb{R}_{>0}^3 := \left\{ \left. \left( x,y,z \right)^\mathsf{T} \in \mathbb{R}^3 \,\right|\, x > 0 \wedge y > 0 \wedge z > 0 \right\}
$$
denote the set of all vectors with strictly positive entries. It is a **subset** of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

In order for a *subset* to be a *subspace* of a given vector space, it is required that it contains the *zero vector* of the original vector space.

The zero vector $\left( 0,0,0 \right)^\mathsf{T} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ is, however, not in $\mathbb{R}_{>0}^3$. Therefore, $\mathbb{R}_{>0}^3$ is **not a subspace** of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Why is this downvoted?